# Bowling Markov chains

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm struggling with a Markov Chain and I hope you can tell me if I'm on the right path.

I want to go Bowling with my colleagues and one of them tells me before that:

- Whenever he hits a strike, he’ll hit another strike in the next round with probability $0.8$.
- If he did not hit a strike, then in the next round he will hit a strike with probability $0.6$.

If this is true and his first attempt is a strike, what is the probability that his fourth attempt is also a strike? What is the long run percentage of strikes for this person for the entire (very long) evening?

I typically see that it is involving Markov chains and I need to construct a transition probability matrix.

Let's say: we have $i$ which can take the value
1 = hit a strike, 0 = doesn't hit a strike, my matrix would look like:

[image]

For the first part, I am asking for $P_{ii}^{(4)}$ if I get it right. How do I find it knowing already P_{ii} ?

For the second part, I should find the two unknown using
[image] and [image] and then find the value we are looking for, namely [image] ?

Comment: For $P^{(4)}=P^4$ just multiply the matrix times itself four times

Comment: It has to be too simple in order for me to not think of it.. Thanks a lot

Comment: To find the value of $\pi_1$ just solve the first equation coupled with $\pi_0+\pi_1=1$

Comment: Fantastic. You were such a great help !